# Issue with awaiting for user input

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I've just started learning discord.js 3 days ago, and I'm coming across this error. I'm trying to make it so if the user says !faction it will ask them to say their faction name, then once they've sent their faction name, it asks them for more information about their faction. Here's my code:

````
factionEmbed = {
title : "Request to create faction.",
color : embedColor,
description : "Please reply with your faction name.",
author : {
name : message.author.username,
icon_url : message.author.displayAvatarURL()
           }
       }
message.channel.send({embeds : [factionEmbed]});

let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
message.channel.send({embeds : []}).then(() => {
message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
max: 1,
time: 30000,
errors: ['time']
           })
           .then(message => {
const nameOfFaction = message.first();
message.channel.send("Please provide us with info about your faction.")
message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
max: 1,
time: 30000,
errors: ['time']
             })
             .then(message => {
const factionInfo = message.content;
message.channel.send("Submitted for review.")
             })
           })
           .catch(collected => {
message.channel.send('Timeout');
           });
       })
   }```
````

Edit:
Error Message:

```
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Halcy\Desktop\BTN Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Halcy\Desktop\BTN Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (C:\Users\Halcy\Desktop\BTN Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:175:15) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/931712816090603545/messages',
  code: 50006,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: [],
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the specific error message you received?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is resulting from you trying to send an empty message, or, more specifically, a message with an empty array of embeds:

```
message.channel.send({embeds : []}).then(() => {
...
})
```

You'll need to either add some content/embeds to that method call, or remove it altogether. It seems to me that you may have intended to include the function passed as a parameter to `then` in a call to `then` for the first message you sent.

Comment: Thank you for the response, that was definetely one of the issues, but now whenever I try use the command it doesn't do anything, nor error.